# How to install elementary tweaks on Freya

Tags: release-freya, software-installation

Similar to the Ubuntu Tweak Tool, elementary OS has a Settings plugin that adds a number of new options.

How to install elementary-tweaks on Freya.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to install elementary tweaks you have to add a PPA. Make sure of knowing the dangers of adding PPAs beforehand.

### elementary OS 0.4 Loki

Make sure you have installed the [program for adding PPAs](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/7508/68). Run the commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks
sudo apt update
sudo apt install elementary-tweaks
```

> According to project page: https://github.com/elementary-tweaks/elementary-tweaks

---

### elementary OS 0.3 Freya

```
curl -sL  http://i-hate-farms.github.io/spores/install | sudo bash - 
sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks
```

From [I hate farms ~ GitHub](https://github.com/I-hate-farms/elementary-tweaks).

---

### elementary OS 0.2 Luna

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:versable/elementary-tweaks-isis
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks
```

From [Versable ~ Elementary Update](https://launchpad.net/~versable/+archive/ubuntu/elementary-update).

Comment: @Tim unclear for what (Luna/Freya/Loki) third way (from GitHub).

Comment: @Tim I have mentioned: for freya

Comment: np, approved :)

Comment: @Tim welcome back :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by running this command in Terminal:

```
curl -sL  http://i-hate-farms.github.io/spores/install | sudo bash - 
sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks
```

Comment: btw are posting answer or giving clarity for [https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2890/elementary-os-freya]