# elementary OS Freya

Tags: themes

Why after i installed elementary-tweaks, Synaptic Package Manager and Gdebi Package Installer my Log-in theme being changed look like Old ubuntu Log-in theme? then there are 2 calculators on my elementary OS freya. any idea please?

Comment: screenshots, please

Comment: Which method did you use to install `elementary-tweaks`?

Comment: @ferry please let me know how you installed `tweaks`

Comment: curl -sL  http://i-hate-farms.github.io/spores/install | sudo bash - 
sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks

Comment: i try with that command after that there's tweak on my system setting then i just added minimize on my elementary after that i restart my elementary then my login theme being changed. but the problem's solved i did new installed :D

Comment: @ferry If your problem solved, you can post your own answer and accept it after 48 hours :)

Comment: @Ravan but now i got message like this Installing the repository...
OK
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 91, in <module>
sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 109, in __init__
self.reload_sourceslist()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 599, in reload_sourceslist
self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 89, in get_sources(self.id, self.codename)