# OS Freya Tweaks won't display in settings

Tags: release-freya

I've tried numbers of different PPAs [from here](http://lmelinux.net/2014/08/11/get-elementary-tweaks-working-freya-beta-1) and none of them seem to work for me. They're all installed, but the settings menu remains unchanged even after reboot. Any help would be great. It could possibly by user issue on my behalf.

Comment: please refer [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2469/how-to-install-elementary-tweaks-on-freya)

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd recommend removing all but the PPAs you have added. They're all out of date. To do that use these 3 commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:bmeznarsic/tweaks-freya
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:versable/elementary-tweaks-isis
```

Then remove and add this ppa:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge elementary-tweaks
sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:justsomedood/justsomeelementary
sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks
```

And then it should be in your settings under Personal:

[image]

if it isn't, try a restart and check again. You could also try to search for "Tweaks".

Finally, if that doesn't work, there seems to be an issue with your install of elementary OS.

Comment: This is bad advice because all three repositories mentioned in the OP post are not actively maintained anymore.

Comment: I'd suggest not to suggest the usage of one of these three repositories.

Comment: @embik I mean, is there an alternative? And how do you know `ppa:versable` is unsupported?

Comment: The most up-to-date version of elementary-tweaks is located at [GitHub](https://github.com/I-hate-farms/elementary-tweaks). However, even this version has not been updated for months and Pull Requests are not processed. There is *no alternative* to suggest. Your answer is bad advice nonetheless.

Comment: @embik So how should he install elementary tweaks? Please don't say he shouldn't. What is **The best way to install**?

Comment: You shouldn't install an **unmaintained** application. Period.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31915/discussion-between-tim-and-embik).