# How can I disable composite and effects in Elementary OS?

Tags: window-manager

I've used Lubuntu for years and felt happy with it. The OS is clear and fast. However, I really like the look of Elementary OS. One thing that stops me is that my computer is not a decent one. A Core 2 Duo might not be good enough for gaming when composite is enabled.

So, are there any ways to disable composite, effects and hot corners too? I would really appreciate.

Comment: `I really like the look of Elementary OS` ~ The look you like will thus be disabled. - eOS may be too heavy. Better add/replace some features in Lubuntu to make it more eOS-like. Take a look at [Project eLubuntu](http://www.theotherinformation.com/2014/04/change-lubuntu-theme-feel-ubuntu.html) (trying to give an Unity-eOS look to LXDE) and at a [MacOS theme for Lubuntu](https://youtu.be/63dDMaSC_Z4) that is not far from eOS look. - You can chose to [install Plank](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/08/install-plank-dock-and-plank-themer.html) instead of Cairo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to disable compositing in elementary OS. If you feel like you need to disable compositing, your computer is probably much too old to be running elementary OS.

Disabling animations could have some impact on performance.

You can disable window animations under System Settings > Universal Access > General. This includes the animations for opening, close, and resizing windows.

You can disable in-app animations through `gsettings` with the Terminal command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations false
```

You can re-enable in-app animations by setting the key to `true` instead of `false`:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations true
```

Bear in mind that in-app animations are not exposed in System Settings because it may cause undesirable behavior. Proceed at your own risk. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: What animations will this disable? Fading? Because It's really laggy.

Comment: @DanielForé using the command `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations false` makes the Applications menu stop showing up in Loki

Comment: @RjQuery whenever you use Terminal to do something, you're going under the hood and risk making modifications that cause breakage. If it worked perfectly and was safe to do in all cases, it would be an option in System Settings ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can disable hot corners in the desktop menu of the system settings. To turn off at least some of the effects, you can use elementary tweaks, which will give you an additional panel in the system settings.

There you can disable animations.

[image]

[image]

For instructions on how to install elementary tweaks see here: [How to install elementary tweaks on Freya](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2469/how-to-install-elementary-tweaks-on-freya)

Comment: So turning off composite is impossible? I mean like you can in Compiz, Metacity and lots more but not in Pantheon?

Comment: I'm not sure about that - I hope someone else will answer that part of the question :)

Comment: @dattutbrus - the Tweaks have an option to disable animations.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use elementary but don't want to use gala (the window manager), you could install a lightweight window manager such as openbox or metacity, and manually run it (using `--replace` to ensure it replaces gala).

However, without compositing, Plank will not display correctly (not a show stopper, but probably not what you want).

Comment: Will replace `gala` disable the top panel thingy? Also will the window title bars work? It seems like `openbox` or `metacity` uses a different theme I guess.

Comment: @dattutbrus `openbox` uses a different theme. `metacity` uses it's own theme engine (some GTK+ theme suites still support it, others don't). Replacing gala with another window manager won't affect your panel, however. The panel is a separate process (`wingpanel`)

Comment: ah k. But there are round corners which needs composite anyway... Also the fading effects which also need Composite. Will it crash?

Comment: With Metacity, you can enable compositing on the CPU using dconf editor. For Openbox, install and run `compton`. Neither will crash.

Comment: I mean like on a few DEs turning off composite glitches the whole thing.

Comment: @dattutbrus you didn't state that very clearly the first time. Anyway, pantheon is quite versatile and it won't crash without compositing.