# Making it work more like Windows

Tags: user-interface, microsoft-windows, tweak-tool

I appreciate it's not Windows, so please don't shoot me down, but after using Windows for 20 years, and trying Linux numerous times, it's never gotten anywhere close, except now, with elementary.   It actually feels quite like my former home, except for 2 things, which I really hope I can change.   They might seem small and insignificant, but they are a HUGE barrier for me, especially as I have no choice but to run Windows at work.

1/ I really need to have the window controls (close/minimize/maximize) on the same side as windows.   It's very tiresome to automatically go to the wrong side each time, having consistency for me, between windows and elementary is essential.

2/ Single Click, Double Click behavior.   Again, for the same reasons, habits are hard to break, and switching between OS and home and OS at work needs to be as seamless as possible.  I need to be able to set a similar Windows style mouse click.

If I can sort these seemingly small, but to me, huge barriers, I think I could really get to love this flavor of Linux.   To the developers, if there was a one-click, "make my OS feel more at home" wizard that make it work like Windows, (or Mac, or other operating systems), setting all these things, this would be a huge step in getting a good early user experience.

Comment: OP, questions on StackExchange should only contain 1 question with a precise answer. If you have multiple questions, please open them separately. Closing this question as "too broad" since it contains multiple questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just install Elementary Tweaks. [Here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2469/how-to-install-elementary-tweaks-on-freya) you can learn how to install it. With that, you can set the double-click behaviour and the location of the window control buttons.

Once installed, go to the system settings->Tweaks and there you'll find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To get the windows style window buttons run the following command in a terminal.

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.appearance button-layout :minimize,maximize,close
```

Log out and back in

Comment: I had tried that, and it gave me some horrible halfway house, where some windows were one way, and others the other way around.  Terminal windows were on the left, Chromium was on the right.