# Is there an available link to download Mac OS icons collection?

Tags: icons

I use a tool named tweak to change my Elementary OS style and I have found some beautiful themes like Yosemite, Unfortunately, I need an icons collection like Mac OS to match the theme. Is there anyone could provide me an avliable link to download these icons? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Closely related to the official Mac OSX icons are the icons of Moka and Faba.
The Faba-Ceru icons are often used to mimic these:

To install them, type this in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:moka/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install faba-icon-theme faba-colors faba-mono-icons
```

Answer (score 0):

I once found an icon pack on [Deviant Art](http://n00b-un-2.deviantart.com/art/OSX-Icon-Theme-for-Gnome-279284710). I did not like it but you can give it a try:

Download ZIP file and unpack into the icon folder:

```
sudo unzip ~/Downloads/my_icon_file.zip -d /usr/share/icons
```

If you have elementary tweaks installed (if not have a look [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2469/how-to-install-elementary-tweaks-on-freya)) you can chose that icon theme.