# How can I add a PPA in Loki?

Tags: release-loki, release-juno

When I went to install aptik, I tried to add the PPA in the terminal as I normally do with:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
```

But I get the message:

```
sudo: apt-add-repository: command not found
```

Undeterred, I downloaded the .deb file and used gdebi (downloaded from the new Software Center) to install it, which it did fine.

But when I open Aptik from the Applications menu, it gives me the following error (see picture).

[image: alert: command not available: add-apt-repository]

What can I do? This is a show stopper for me if I can't add a PPA to restore my backup.

Comment: Related: [How can I install .deb files in Loki?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/7542/5565)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As far as I know it is intentional from the eOS team. I also had such issues in Loki beta. In order to add PPAs run the following in the terminal

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
```

Comment: I installed this via the Software Center as Software & Updates, and now I can add ppas! Thanks!! Should I disable all updates? I don't want it pulling down updates that will break my system.

Comment: This was an intentional change by the elementary team IIRC to prevent adding PPAs. Don't disable updates - this is normal and you'll be fine

Comment: @kingogames remember to mark this answer as accepted if it solved your issue.

Comment: @dan Do you know why they disabled?

Comment: This has been a fairly common practice in multiple modern distros as it helps avoid unintentional package injection by default.

Comment: @Samuel What modern distros (besides Elementary)?  This is a common practice for those trying to create a walled garden environment out of an open source OS.

Answer (score 5):

The following should install the tool to add apt repositories. Remember that elementary doesn't support or secure these, so they are entirely at your own risk.

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common python3-software-properties python-software-properties
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also just install "Software & Updates" from the app center.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to run sudo apt-get update first I had to do this for the software properties to work