# How can I install .deb files in Loki?

Tags: release-loki, appcenter

In the latest version (Loki 0.4 Stable), I can't open .deb files with AppCenter, like Ubuntu.

Comment: A note from [another question](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/8401/5565): there are two gdebi installers in AppCenter and the one without the Debian icon worked better for this user

Answer (score 57, accepted):

#### Use Eddy (the recommended, graphical, elementary way)

[Read this other answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/13235/26) about using Eddy, which can be [installed in AppCentre](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.eddy).

#### Use `gdebi-cli`

```
sudo gdebi package.deb
```

#### Use `gdebi` GUI

```
sudo apt install gdebi
```

Then open the package using `gdebi`

#### Use `apt` (the proper cli way)

```
sudo apt install ./package.deb
```

#### Use `dpkg` (the way that doesn't resolve dependencies)

```
sudo dpkg -i package.deb
sudo apt install -f
```

Note that attempting to install a .deb that is inside an .iso can cause errors, so you may want to copy it to your downloads folder.

Comment: I didn't know that you could install local .deb packages with apt. Thanks for that. About gdebi, does it resolves dependencies?

Comment: It tries too, but it doesn't always work.

Comment: gdebi can also be found in the AppCenter as GDebu Package Installer. This way no terminal is required.

Comment: I wasn't able to use gdebi, it didn't accept my password, it asks for the user root password?!? Well looks like i'ts not trying to do a "sudo", thats strange (fresh loki install as of yesterday) - the other answer with gnome-software was fine

Comment: This answer is so freaking helpful I wish I could upvote 10x!

Comment: Eddy isn't free on appcenter though

Answer (score 10):

One easy way to install Debian files easily is to install Eddy. Run this command to install it

```
sudo apt install eddy
```

As Seth noted out in the comments, the previous does not work in Elementary OS 5.0 Juno. Try this instead:

```
sudo apt install com.github.donadigo.eddy
```

To install a Debian package with Eddy first you open it and it will show this page:

[image]

If you downloaded the Debian package into your Downloads folder, you can click the "Load from Download" option. It will then show the screen below. Then you can click install on whatever package you need to.

[image]

Or, you can select the "Open" button. It will show the file manager and you can choose what file you want to install.

Comment: For others in the future looking at this question. As of September 2017 this is the correct answer as the software for Elementary OS has matured and this is the best curated .deb installer for Elementary and can also be found featured on the app store.

Comment: Installing via apt using the short name does not appear to work on Juno 5.0. Try `sudo apt install com.github.donadigo.eddy` instead.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the options already provided. Or you can install Gnome Software.

```
sudo apt install gnome-software
```

Gnome Software is the new shop for `Ubuntu 16.04`. With it you can install the `.deb` package, and the same list these softwares installed, options that the AppCenter doesn't have.

The Gnome Software does not disable AppCenter.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use **gdebi** app. Install it first from your Terminal

```
sudo apt install gdebi
```

Then use gdebi to install the .deb file

Answer (score 3):

You can use command **dpkg** in terminal to install .deb files.

Usage: **sudo dpkg --install** */path/to/deb/file.deb*