# Chrome install issues in Loki

Tags: google-chrome

After installing Loki and downloading the latest version of Chrome, I haven't been able to install it. I've tried both GDebi and the terminal as well as several different downloads, but both tell me the package is nonexistent.

The exact text in GDebi is:
      A nonexistent package has been selected for installation. Please select an existing .deb package file.

In the terminal:
        error processing archive google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7542/how-can-i-install-deb-files-in-loki

Answer (score 0):

*Note - This is not a solution to your problem, rather a way to get Chrome working.*

I faced similar issue and just to save some time and effort, looked for Chromium in the new app store. Turns out you have one! The chromium in the new app store is at version 52 and works perfectly fine, without the need to use gdebi, apt-get install, etc.

If you aren't hell bent on installing Google Chrome (the .deb from their webpage) then Chromium (open source) works just fine! I have been using it since installing Loki and no problem whatsoever :)

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem, you can try this commomon on terminal :

> $ sudo apt-get install -f

My problem fixed with that...