# Problems to install .deb package

Tags: release-loki, software-installation

I'm having problems installing .deb packages. I tried to install vscode and chrome and failed.

The error suggests to enter a .deb package, when installing with terminal need run `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` and `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Comment: Did you run the commands that you mentioned, or did you get an error message saying you needed to run those commands? Can you copy and paste the exact error message? Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you are in the same dir as your desired .deb files in your terminal.

Comment: See more options of how to install `.deb` [here.](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7542/how-can-i-install-deb-files-in-loki/7664)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go by command line, there are numerous ways to install the .deb packages but I’ll go with the simplest one. Open a terminal and use the following command:

`sudo apt install (path to deb package)`

Source: https://itsfoss.com/fix-application-installation-issues-elementary-os-loki/

Answer (score 2):

Install gdebi :

> sudo apt-get install gdebi

Now, right click on the .deb pckage and select to open it with gdebi.