# Gdebi not installing .deb from within Files explorer

Tags: system

I'm brand new to eOS, but I've used other linux distros before.

I have installed Gdebi ok.

My problem is that Gdebi isn't working properly when I run it after clicking on a file in Files explorer and run 'Open With' an error box appears- "unable to open files or uris with this app".

It installs everything ok if run from within Applications- it's UI finds, opens and installs without issue.

Is the problem with the installation of Gdebi ( I've reinstalled several times), or with Files? I've tried different .deb files so an isolated corrupt .deb file is not the issue.

Thanks for any help available.

Comment: There are two gdebi installers in AppCenter. You need to install the one without the Debian icon. https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7542/how-can-i-install-deb-files-in-loki

Comment: You have solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For quite some time, I used another application called `Eddy` available on the AppCenter. However, I had some issues with dependencies.

If one doesn't have enough knowledge of `dpkg` and `apt`, I'd still suggest using 'GDebi.' I don't know why the GUI front-end gives problems in Elementary OS. I guess this is because if you open `GDebi` from a regular user account, it freezes since it is somehow prevented from asking `sudo` permissions.

My solution is to run `GDebi` from command line under `sudo`, that is

```
sudo  gdebi  path_to/file.deb
```

I never had issues with this approach.