# Installing .deb file with a double-click

Tags: appcenter

I just installed Elementary OS and some applications aren't available in the [AppCenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_OS#Development) such as Chrome, so I downloaded the *.deb* file, but I cannot double-click to install it.

[An answer suggested](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7542/how-can-i-install-deb-files-in-loki/7664#7664) to install *gnome-software* which I did, but now I have two app centers... Is there a way to incorporate that double-click feature in the native AppCenter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, that was an awful suggestion.

### First

Always, always, ALWAYS! make sure you can trust the deb you've downloaded.

### Before you install a .deb

Before telling you how to install it, I would ask you to check if they have the software in:

#### Flathub

[flathub](https://flathub.org/home) because then you can click install there, download the .ref, click it in files, and appcenter will offer to install it for you (which will add flathub as a source in appcenter, allowing you to search their apps through it). flatpaks run in confinement, and this adds a layer of security as they can't access all parts of your system (well, in theory)

#### Snap store

Now, elementary OS does not have direct snap support, in that, `snapd` is not installed by default. But this is another 'containerized' format, snapd keeps these apps up to date, which can either be annoying or practical depending on how you look at it.

If you decide to use snaps, I would suggest doing the following:

1. you can read instructions to [get started with snapd here](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-elementary-os)
2. install the third party snap frontend for elementary OS developed by Bart Zaalberg available [here](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.bartzaalberg.snaptastic)
3. Go to the [snap store](https://snapcraft.io/store) and install apps by clicking the install button in the right upper corner, and then clicking 'desktop store' then your URL handler should ask you how you want to open the URL for which you choose snaptastic.

### Your options for installing a .deb the GUI way

So far as i am aware, you have two options for installing .debs through the GUI

#### Eddy

Well, to install a .deb, i recommend installing [Eddy](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.eddy) it's a curated app, so it looks native, and lives in the AppCenter. The only thing I would note here, is that I have had a situation where it did not install a dependency.

#### gDebi

If you want to have more details available whilst installing, you might go for gdebi instead, which you can also find in AppCenter. it is not a native app though and can look a bit weird.

### Lastly the CLI option

If you decide to go the CLI route instead you can right click in your folder where the package (lets call it: blah.deb) is reciding, and click "open in terminal" and then type the following command:

`sudo dpkg -i blah.deb`

this may result in a partial install, say, if there are uninstalled dependencies, so you might want to follow it up with:

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: any reason why most apps aren't available on AppCenter but on the one provided by gnome-software?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'most apps' maybe out allows you to browse snaps visually too, but again, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Eddy, which is a free .deb installer on the AppCenter.

How to use:

1. Install Eddy (A restart might be necessary)
2. Open Eddy
3. Press the "Open" button. This will open the "Files" app.
4. Choose the Debian package you want to install.
5. This will automatically load into Eddy.
6. Now just press install. You might be prompted to type your password.
7. The App should now be installed. You might have to restart when the App is not shown on the menu.

Comment: After installing Eddy, it should be the default program for .deb and so clicking on any such in files you open it in Eddy